# How to know specific view controller already exists in memory?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to use unwind segue to make transition to a specific view controller.
But if that view controller not exists in memory yet, it won't do anything.
Is there a way to check any view controller already exists in memory?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!myViewController)
NSLog("myViewController is not around");
```

IIUC, isn't this what you are looking for ?